# How to set up effective cron jobs for a web crawler

Tags: php, web-crawler, cron-task

I have written a php web crawler to index content of only 180 specific sources, but it takes an average of 2 seconds per page to analyze, grab and save the content i want: image, url, title, full content, excerpt, tags. (there are several algorithms that analyze all meta tags to get the correct data)

I only crawl the latest 9 article pages, so it takes me like 18-25 seconds per source.

I have created 10 different cron jobs (6 minutes between them), so each can handle 18 sources (around 350 seconds).

That seems very inefficient especially if I want to reach 1k sources. What should I modify?

ps: I'm testing it on a shared hosting, would a dedicated server reduce the time substantially?

cron jobs are something like:

lynx -auth username:password website.com/crawler.php?group=1

lynx -auth username:password website.com/crawler.php?group=2

lynx -auth username:password website.com/crawler.php?group=3
etc.

and the crawler script visits 18 sources from database, takes the latest 9 article pages and crawls the content, analyze it and based on the results, it stores it in database.

Comment: is your server fully utilized during a cron-job run? would it hurt to have them run in parallel? maybe you could speed up the thing if you seperate the crawling and the indexing. `wget` is very good and fast in crawling. let it do its work and index the downloaded files with your php script.

Comment: it would be more efficient, if you could run the crawler.php script directly without the webserver and lynx in between.

Comment: and how am i supposed to do that.. would creating daemons be better? as bigman says?

Comment: you need to be able to run the php script directly from the command line. if its not possible in your shared server you need a dedicated machine (or virtual machine with root access). if you use a daemon or cron-job doesn't matter for efficiency. you need to make sure that the task itself is as efficient as possible. running a script from command line or in cronjob is as simple as `/usr/bin/php /path/to/crawlscript.php arg1 arg2 argN`

Comment: so basically I need to modify the algorithm, that s the main problem? and why is the command line faster than cpanel cron job

Comment: problem is not in cpanel but in the overhead the lynx and apache processes and the extra tcp connections provide. and 2 seconds per page is definitely to long. try experimenting with different solutions. and split the tasks `download` and `analyze` and enhance them seperately

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, don't use cron jobs for this.  Setup a Daemon, it will run all the time. Respawn if it crashes and so on.

http://pear.php.net/package/System_Daemon